# How to fix AssertionError while building Gradle project?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea

I am getting an error while building my gradle project

Is anyone know the solution?

**Infos**:

*idea version*:IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1.2 (Ultimate Edition)

*SDK*:Correcto-17

*Language Level*:17

**The Error**

```
Exception during working with external system: java.lang.AssertionError
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.CommonGradleProjectResolverExtension.createModule(CommonGradleProjectResolverExtension.java:122)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.createModule(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:80)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.gradleJava.configuration.kpm.KotlinKPMGradleProjectResolver.createModule(KotlinKPMGradleProjectResolver.kt:46)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.createModule(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:80)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.gradleJava.configuration.KotlinMPPGradleProjectResolver.createModule(KotlinMPPGradleProjectResolver.kt:77)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.createModule(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:80)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.createModule(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:80)
```

more...

Comment: Is this of any help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53442569/intellij-2018-3-java-lang-assertionerror-when-refresh-gradle-project

Comment: I looked before asking but couldn't get help in that question's advices :/

Comment: Looks like from the answers on that page there are multiple possible causes of this error.  Go through each one, I.E. make sure you are not in offline mode, running clean build etc.

Comment: Looks like this known issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-284721